# Swift : Failed to import bridging header while archiving in Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I'm archiving an iOS app through jenkins as a part of continuous integration process using xcode as a build tool. we have three frameworks integrated with the app. everything is working fine but suddenly i'm getting the below issue while building in jenkins.

```
Bridging-Header.h:25:9: error: 'xxx/xxy.h' file not found
import xxx/xxy.h
error: failed to import bridging header '/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxx_App-Bridging-Header.h'
** BUILD FAILED *****
```

when i build separately in xcode(7.3.1) Build succeeds but through jenkins it fails with above error.

Comment: @kirit Sry it did'nt work. In xcode when i build it succeeds but when in jenkins its unable to locate the framework class file while importing bridging header.

Comment: @suresh remove your bridge file and again You follow all steps in this tutorial again and adding Your framework and Objective-C file in bridge header.

Comment: @suresh see my answer to fail import to import bridge header.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the support. I solved it myself and the workaround is to add the defined framework under the target dependencies and also need to add the path inherited in the framework search path at project level because jenkins always checks as an initiality while importing xcode for build generation.

Comment: @suresh your answer helped me to give a correct direction but its not clear what you were trying to say so for others who are facing similar issue here is the answer: Goto your project build settings->Search Paths->Header Search paths and then drag and drop your framework paths(like "$(SRCROOT)/Headers/Private/CorePlot/ios") here one by one and then clean and build the project. This resolved my archiving issue.

Comment: Yep..Exactly but make sure that the framework is added under target dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error :

[image]

**failed to import bridging header '/Users/MyName/Desktop/AppleDemo123/AppleDemo-Bridging-Header.h'**

**Solution:**

You check all import file in your bridge header file, You are removed file in your project, But it it already import in bridge header file.

Removed the import file from `Bridging-Header.h` file.

Comment: You are check all file, Where some import file doen't.

Comment: Above see  my image "VidecontrollerApple.h" file doen't in my folder, but it is already import in bridge file. then Above error occurs.

Comment: xxx/xxy.h what is original name of file ?

Comment: LmImageEditor/ImageProtocolEdit.h

Comment: LmImageEditor/ImageProtocolEdit.h file is not in your project. Search in project.

Comment: ImageProtocolEdit.h File is there @kirit. But as it's a framework the class file mentioned is not importing through header.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in xcode which it doesn't fill out the "SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER[arch=*]" so open project.pbxproj in a text editor find that field and make sure that the bridging header is set then it should work!